# How to select the sum of sales for last week (unix time) with mysql pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get the sum of the sales for the last week / month with php and mysql pdo. The sales date saved in unix timestamp format in database.

This is how I'm doing it right now;

```
$week = strtotime("+1 Week");
$getsales = $odb -> prepare("SELECT SUM(`amount`)  FROM `sales` WHERE `date` < :date");
$getsales -> execute(array(':date' => $week));
```

Can someone give me a better way for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function to convert date into timestamp and use it in  the query, e.g.:

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`)  
FROM `sales` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW() -7 DAYS)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)'s the documentation for `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for a way to do it without any parameters, like direct sql command to obtain last week sales sum

Comment: Thank you so much.